# How to make keyboard work on Linux Mint FXCE on 2 in 1 ? (Keyboard not detected, touch x,y are out of sync)

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard, touch-screen

#### No input works

| Issue | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Issue 1 | keyboard is not detected |
| Issue 2 | touchscreen registers touches but under different coordination. |
| Reproduction | Booting into desktop from bootable USB with Linux Mint FXCE |

Basically both ways to use input are not working so i can't do anything with desktop (terminal or UI).

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Device | [Yoga Duet 7 13IML05 (intel i7 10th gen, 16GB ram)](https://www.lenovo.com/il/en/laptops/yoga/duet-series/Yoga-Duet-7-13IML05/p/88YGD701446) |
| Other installed OS | Windows 11 |
| Issues with OS | Linux Mint FXCE 21.1 64bit |
| More | Maybe irrelevant but [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Lenovo_Yoga_Duet_7_13IML05) is only mention of the device and Linux i found at [wiki.archlinux.org](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Lenovo_Yoga_Duet_7_13IML05) |

I've tried to search solution to no avail. Everything boils down to type this and that to terminal however i can't use any form of keyboard / mouse i have at disposal.
Anything else i can do ? Maybe changing something on bootable USB ?